# Ordenar registros de una tabla a partir de otros de otra tabla MYSQL

Tags: mysql

mi problema es el siguiente.Necesito una consulta que me ordene un listado de articulos por la cantidad de comentarios que tenga cada uno.Tengo una Tabla

`Articulo(id,titulo,contenido)`

y otra

`Comentario(id,id_articulo,comentario,id_usuario)`

Destacar que todos los `articulos` no tienen comentarios,por lo tanto si se ordenan en forma descendente esos `articulos` que no tienen comentarios deberian aparecer al final.

Comment: por favor añade lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento

Comment: Por favor lee el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque no sabemos lo suficiente sobre tu base de datos.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2880/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que esto es lo que necesitas

```
SELECT 
    id,titulo,contenido, COUNT(*) suma
FROM
    articulos
        INNER JOIN
    comentarios ON articulos.id = comentarios.id_articulo
GROUP BY id,titulo,contenido
ORDER BY suma DESC
```

El método Join te ayuda a consultar dos tablas que estan relacionada entre si (Como en la solucion) realizas un count(*) para sumar el numero de registro que te devuelve la consulta agrupando por los campos de la tabla articulos ya que se pueden repetir si el articulo tiene mas de un comentrio y terminas ordenando de forma descendente por la suma para que te saque los articulos con más comentarios

Comment: no es solo colocar código, lo debes explicar

Answer (score 0):

Podes unir la tabla articulo por medio de un left join con la tabla comentario, de esta forma luego de hacer un count y agrupar podes ordenar en base a ese total, en el caso de la consulta que pongo ordena ede forma descendente segun el total de comentarios y luego si los totales son iguales ordena e A - Z segun el titulo.
Haciendo el left si no encuentra comentarios pone el valor en 0.

```
SELECT a.id, a.titulo, a.contenido, count(c.id) as totalComentario
from articulo a left join comentario c on a.id = c.id_articulo
group by a.id order by totalComentario desc, a.id asc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo un link donde estan bien explicados todos los tipos de join que podes hacer con ejemplos https://diego.com.es/principales-tipos-de-joins-en-sql